# C# 32feet.Net: Handling two bluetooth connections in seperate threads, gives SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets, bluetooth, 32feet

I'm writing a C# console application using the `32feet.Net` library that creates two threads to search for and connect to different Bluetooth devices and then open up TCP sockets so that data can be passed to the devices via a network connection. I know this situation sounds completely bizarre, but I've been asked to do this by a senior colleague.

My code seems to work OK with only one device connected, although the Bluetooth connection does sometimes drop out after a couple of messages have been passed backwards and forwards. However, sometimes as soon as the second device connects I get an error saying `System.net.sockets.socketexception a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond`, other times the code just exits without throwing any exceptions.

I was wondering what is causing this, I've seen that the `32feet.Net` library can support multiple connections. I'm wondering if I've made some errors, as I'm new to `C#`, `.Net`, and even Windows, and have never written any Bluetooth based code before.

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace BluetoothManager
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BTManager rover_btm = new BTManager();
        BTManager base_btm = new BTManager();
        base_btm.Port = 0xba5e;
        rover_btm.Port = 17825;
        base_btm.Name = "Base";
        rover_btm.Name = "Rover";

        base_btm.match = (args.Length >= 1 && args[0] != "") ? args[0] : "dev1";
        rover_btm.match = (args.Length >= 2 && args[1] != "") ? args[1] : "dev2";

        Console.WriteLine("Base Station match: " + base_btm.match);
        Console.WriteLine("Rover match: " + rover_btm.match);
        Thread Base = new Thread(new ThreadStart(base_btm.HandleThread));
        Thread Rover = new Thread(new ThreadStart(rover_btm.HandleThread));

        Base.Start();
        Rover.Start();

        Base.Join();
        Rover.Join();

        Console.Read();

    }
}
}
```

**BTManager.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net.Ports;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;


namespace BluetoothManager
{
class BTManager
{
    private static BluetoothDeviceInfo[] peers;
    private BluetoothClient client;
    private bool _isConnected = false;
    private string _match;
    private const string defpin = "0000";
    private TcpListener tcpListener;
    private int _port;
    private string _name = "Not Named";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public int Port
    {
        get { return _port; }
        set { _port = value; }
    }

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return _isConnected; }
        private set { _isConnected = value; }
    }

    public string match
    {
        get { return _match; }

        set { _match = value; }
    }

    public BTManager()
    {
        client = new BluetoothClient();
    }


    public void HandleThread()
    {

        BluetoothDeviceInfo device;
        while (!this.findDevice(out device)) ;

        Console.WriteLine("About to pair");
        int count = 0;
        int max = 5;
        while ((!(BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress, defpin))) && count < max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pairing Failed, retrying");
            count++;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        if (count == max)
        {
            HandleThread();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Paired..Beginning connect");
            client.BeginConnect(device.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort, this.callback, client);
        }
    }

    private void callback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        client.EndConnect(result);

        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, _port);
        this.tcpListener.Start();
        TcpClient TcpClient = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream networkStream = TcpClient.GetStream();
        Stream bluetoothStream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] fromNetwork = new byte[1024];
        byte[] fromBluetooth = new byte[1024];
        while (client.Connected && TcpClient.Connected)
        {

            try
            {
                if (networkStream.CanRead)
                {
                    Array.Clear(fromNetwork, 0, 1024);
                    networkStream.Read(fromNetwork, 0, 1024);
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromNetwork));
                    bluetoothStream.Write(fromNetwork, 0, 1024);
                    bluetoothStream.Flush();

                    while (bluetoothStream.CanRead)
                    {
                        Array.Clear(fromBluetooth, 0, 1024);
                        bluetoothStream.Read(fromBluetooth, 0, 1024);
                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fromNetwork));
                        networkStream.Write(fromBluetooth, 0, 1024);
                        networkStream.Flush();
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }

        this.HandleThread();
    }

    private bool findDevice(out BluetoothDeviceInfo device)
    {
        peers = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
        device = Array.Find(peers, element => element.DeviceName == match);

        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo btdi in peers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(btdi.DeviceName);
        }


        if (device == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name +": Not Found");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name +": Found");
            return true;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sockets in order to communicate with the Bluetooth device.
Its very important to release any resources when disconnecting.

In order to find your COM port you can use  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439091/how-to-get-bluetooth-device-com-serial-port-in-winform-c/27919129#27919129)

Your stream is located here:

```
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream = bthClient.GetStream();
```

Example to how to connect and find your device.

```
private InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient _BTClient = null;
private InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothDeviceInfo[] _clientDevices;



    /// <summary>
    /// Thread function to discover devices
    /// </summary>
    private void DiscoverBluetoothThread()
    {
        try
        {                                
            _BTClient = new InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient();
            _clientDevices = _BTClient.DiscoverDevices(999, _authenticated, _remembered, _unknown);
            _BTClient.Dispose();
            _BTClient = null;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

    }


    Private void Connect(InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothDeviceInfo info)
    {
        string addressN = info.DeviceAddress.ToString("N"); //Format Example: "00066606E014"
        string addressC = info.DeviceAddress.ToString("C"); //Format Example: "00:06:66:06:E0:14"
        string addressP = info.DeviceAddress.ToString("P"); //Format Example: "00.06.66.06.E0.14"
        string addressD = info.DeviceAddress.ToString();    //Format Example: "00066606E014"

        string serialPort = FindBluetoothPortName(addressN);
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439091/how-to-get-bluetooth-device-com-serial-port-in-winform-c/27919129#27919129

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serialPort) == false && serialPort.Trim().Length > "COM".Length)
            bool installed = InstallBluetoothDevice(addressC, passKey, autoConnect);
    }


     public bool InstallBluetoothDevice(string deviceMACAddress, string passKey, bool connect)
     {
        string strDevicePassKey = passKey;
        string BTMac = deviceMACAddress;

        InTheHand.Net.BluetoothAddress BTAddress;
        InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient BTClient = new InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient();
        InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint BTEndPoint;
        InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothRadio BTRadio;

        BTRadio = InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio;
        BTRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Connectable;

        Guid spguid = BluetoothService.SerialPort;
        BTAddress = InTheHand.Net.BluetoothAddress.Parse(BTMac);
        BTEndPoint = new InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint(BTAddress, spguid);            
        try
        {
            BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(BTAddress, strDevicePassKey);
            //Application.DoEvents();
            BTClient = new InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient();

            if (connect)
            {
                BTClient.Connect(BTEndPoint);
                BTEndPoint = new InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint(BTAddress, spguid);
                _connectedDevices.Add(BTAddress, BTClient);
                return BTClient.Connected;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;

        }

    }
```