# Bluetooth C# using 32feet.net to connect to a speaker

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am currently trying use 32feet.net to connect to a bluetooth speaker that once shutdown (the computer or the speaker) they stay paired but they dont auto reconnect. Therefore I want to make an windows service that tries to reconnect to it every so often if its not connected and if it can find it.

I have tried

[C# 32feet.Net: Handling two bluetooth connections in seperate threads, gives SocketException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379705/c-sharp-32feet-net-handling-two-bluetooth-connections-in-seperate-threads-give)

Code but for some reason there is a few things that light up red.

I am also trying to figure out and make this code work at the same time for the same purpose

```
public void btconnect()
    {
        List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
        InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient bc = new InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient();
        InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothDeviceInfo[] array = bc.DiscoverDevices();
        int count = array.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
        {
            Device device = new Device(array[i]);
            devices.Add(device);
        }

        foreach(Device d in devices)
        {
            if (d.DeviceInfo.ToString().Equals("myphonesdevicenumber"))
            {
            Guid MyServiceUuid
            = new Guid("{00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff}"); // found this somewhere not sure what the string represents.

                byte[] guidbytearray = d.DeviceInfo.ToByteArray(); // guid as a byte array.
                string guidstring = d.DeviceInfo.ToString(); //guid as a string.
                Int64 guid64 = d.DeviceInfo.ToInt64(); // guid as an int64.

                Guid g = new Guid(guidbytearray);




                bc.Connect(d.DeviceInfo,MyServiceUuid);
            // turnoff = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

List devices = new List();

in the orignal code this wasnt there and I dont know if he was using (Device) it from a external reference or not.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more detail. No one will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the article of 32feet, they list an inner-class named `Device`. You should use it in your program.
The Guid is the identifier for the socket used to connect to your BT device.
The format is a 32 digit long of hex numbers divided into group of 8, 4 ,4 ,4 and 12. Between the groups there is a '-'.